# is there any way to partial instance a c++ template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization

I have a template for some type, and some code in the template are not valid for all types, so I want to skip them when needed.

```
struct T1
{
    int getData(){return 1;}
};

struct T2
{
    string getData(){return "string";}
};

struct T3
{
    // no getData()
};

template<typename T>
void printData(T param)
{
    cout << param.getData() << endl;
}

int main() {

    T1 t1;
    T2 t2;
    T3 t3;

    printData(t1);
    printData(t2);
    printData(t3);  // fails for T3 has no getData
}
```

I want to know is there some way like this(pseudo code):

```
template<typename T>
void printData(T param)
{
    if(T != T3) // compile time check, instance on this condition
    {
        cout << param.getData() << endl;
    }
}
```

I have tried `std::is_same` but it did not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from C++17, you can use `if constexpr (!std::is_same_v<T, T3>)`, as suggested in songyuanyao's answer.

In C++11/C++14 I propose two ways.

(1) tag dispatching

```
template <typename T>
void printData (T param, std::true_type)
 { }

template <typename T>
void printData (T param, std::false_type)
 { std::cout << param.getData() << std::endl; }

template <typename T>
void printData (T param)
 { printData(param, std::is_same<T, T3>{}); }
```

(2) SFINAE

```
// ever enabled
template <typename T>
void printData (T param, long)
 { }

// preferred (int instead of long) but enabled only
// when param support getData()
template <typename T>
auto printData (T param, int)
   -> decltype( param.getData(), void() )
 { std::cout << param.getData() << std::endl; }

template <typename T>
void printData (T param)
 { printData(param, 0); }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the statement_true will still be evaluated in compilation when `T` is `T3`, which leads to compilation error.

You could use [Constexpr If](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) (since C++17).

> If the value is `true`, then statement-false is discarded (if present), otherwise, statement-true is discarded.

e.g.

```
if constexpr (!std::is_same_v<T, T3>)
{
    cout << param.getData() << endl;
}
```